# Salesforce Mobile SDK: Get all possible values for a Picklist field

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Where can I find information how to request all possible values for a `Picklist` field using the Mobile SDK?

I expected them to be in the Metadata WSDL since there are already a lot of `enumeration` entries - but there is nothing.

**Edit:**

I found a way to get all the values for a `Picklist` field using `SFRestAPI`.
Is this the way to go or is there a more elegant solution?

```
let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForDescribe(withObjectType: "MyObjectType")
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, fail: { (error) in
    // Handle error
}) { (result) in
    // Picklist values and a lot more is hiding in the `result` (Optional String)
    // Parse JSON String and do something with it
}
```